# Persisting a Large scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, persistence, sparse-matrix

I have a very large sparse scipy matrix. Attempting to use `save_npz` resulted in the following error:

```
>>> sp.save_npz('/projects/BIGmatrix.npz',W)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 716, in _savez
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 597, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: 6257005295 requested and 3283815408 written

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_matrix_io.py", line 78, in save_npz
    np.savez_compressed(file, **arrays_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 659, in savez_compressed
    _savez(file, args, kwds, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 721, in _savez
    raise IOError("Failed to write to %s: %s" % (tmpfile, exc))
OSError: Failed to write to /projects/BIGmatrix.npzg6ub_z3y-numpy.npy: 6257005295 requested and 3283815408 written
```

As such I wanted to try persisting it to postgres via `psycopg2` but I haven't found a method of iterating over all nonzeros so I can persist them as rows in a table.

What is the best way to handle this task?

Comment: Another report of this `OSError`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657939/oserror-269892000-requested-and-269188084-written,  What's the size of this matrix, shape and `nnz` (number of nonzero values)?  `save_npz` is using the basic `numpy` `savez` to the matrix attributes (3 main arrays) to a `zip` archive.  For some reason, possibly some sort of disk or directory space issue, the operating system is having problems with this save.

Comment: The question @hpaulj linked to has a link to a corresponding numpy issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5336.   It could be that you don't have enough space in your /tmp directory.  Try adding the argument `compressed=False` to the `save_npz()` call.

Comment: hmm interesting. so it sound like perhaps behind the scenes, numpy is saving a temporary uncompressed version in `tmp` before compressing and shipping it to the target path? thanks for the links to the other SO post and github issue. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Save all the attributes in `__dict__` of the matrix object, and recreate the `csr_matrix` when load:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((1000, 2000))
a[np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100), np.random.randint(0, 2000, 100)] = np.random.randn(100)

b = sparse.csr_matrix(a)

np.savez("tmp", data=b.data, indices=b.indices, indptr=b.indptr, shape=np.array(b.shape))
f = np.load("tmp.npz")
b2 = sparse.csr_matrix((f["data"], f["indices"], f["indptr"]), shape=f["shape"])
(b != b2).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way things go is:

When you invoke `scipy.sparse.save_npz()`, by default it saves as a compressed file; however, in order to do so it first creates a temporary *uncompressed* version of the target file that it then compresses down to the final result. This means that whatever drive you save to needs to be large enough to accommodate the uncompressed temp file which in my case was 47G.

I re-tried the save in a larger drive and the process completed without incident.

Note: The compression can take quite a long time.